# Can't resize /dev/sda2 extended partition with gparted live cd

Tags: partition, livecd, gparted, disk-encryption

I recently got a message while updating some programs that my `/boot` is full. I've been on other posts and everyone says delete files in `/boot` but I thought making it bigger seems more logical and better long-term if it gets full again. I right clicked on the `/dev/sda2` and click resize but it doesn't move. Any ideas?

[image]

If this doesn't work I'll use SystemRescueCd and try again.

Comment: Did you shrink the other partition first? If you have no free space, you can't expand a partition

Comment: I tried to shrink the sda2 partition so I can expand the boot partition. But the buttons are not pressable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's definitely due to the encryption. GParted sees such as un-partitioned - so can't do much to it.

Unfortunately it's going to be a command-line fix only. Here's a writeup on how to do it under Ubuntu: [ResizeEncryptedPartitions - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions)